# Improvements of Random Search for Hyperparameter Optimization

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, hyperparameters

Random search is one possibility for hyperparameter optimization in machine learning. I have applied random search to search for the best hyperparameters of a SVM classifier with a RBF kernel. Additional to the continuous Cost and gamma parameter, I have one discrete parameter and also an equality constraint over some parameters.

Now, I would like to develop random search further, e.g. through adaptive random search. That means for example adaptation of the search direction or of the search range.

Does somebody have an idea how this can be done or could reference to some existing work on this? Other ideas for improving random search are also welcome.

Comment: This is a site for programming questions. Your question would be more appropriate on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you try to reinvent the wheel? Hyperparameters optimization is well studied topic, with at least few of the state of the art method, which simply solve the problem for SVMs, including:

- Bayesian optimization (usually through modeling model quality with Gaussian processes), see for example bayesopt http://rmcantin.bitbucket.org/html/
- Tree of parzen estimators (sometimes better for discrete, complex hyperparameters spaces) included (in particular) in hyperopt http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/

Comment: Thank you for the hint but I would like to improve my random search strategy and not switching to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the random search procedure, you can refer to [Hyperband](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~kjamieson/hyperband.html).

Hyperband is a method proposed by UC Berkeley AMP Lab, aiming to improve the efficiency of tuning method like random search.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that [Bayesian optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization) is a perfect example of an *adaptive random search*, so looks like it's exactly what you want to apply.

The idea of Bayesian optimization is to model the target function using [Gaussian Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process) (GP), select the best next point according to the current model and update the model after seeing the actual outcome. So, effectively, Bayesian optimization starts like a random search, gradually builds a picture of what the function looks like and shifts its focus to the most promising areas (note that "promising" can be defined differently by different particular methods - PI, EI, UCB, etc). There are further techniques to help it to find a right balance between exploration and exploitation, for example [portfolio strategy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5419.pdf). If that's what you mean by *adaptive*, then Bayesian optimization is your choice .

If you'd like to extend your code without external libraries, it's totally possible because Bayesian optimization is not that hard to implement. You can take a look at sample code that I used in [my research](https://github.com/maxim5/hyper-engine), for example [here](https://github.com/maxim5/hyper-engine/blob/master/hyperengine/bayesian/utility.py) is the bulk of GP-related code.